# Create Line Chart and populate with database information

Tags: django, chart.js, linechart

I want to create a line chart on my html, and the information has to be from the database.

This is the view:

```
def data(request, id):
    return render(request, 'interface/data.html', {'user_id': id})
```

This user_id, is the primary key of the model User. This user has multiple 'Data'. The data model is the following:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    x = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    y = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    z = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

And this is the html:

```
{% extends './default.html' %}
{% block child_content %}

<body>
    <h2 class="square_margin" style="text-align:center"> Información paciente: <strong> {{ user_id }} </strong> </h2>

    <!-- HERE GOES THE LINE CHART -->

    <form class="square square_margin"> <button class="btn btn-warning btn-md btn-block" formaction="{% url 'interface:modify' user_id %}"> Modificar Ajustes Paciente </button></form>
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

I want to populate that line chart with the Data information of that User.

On the X axis is going to be the time (Data has a timestamp). And the Y axis the acceleration, that is represented by x,y,z from the Data model.

How I can do that with [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org)

I need something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your data to the web template.  Something like:

```
def data(request, id):
    variables = {}
    variables['line1'] = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    variables['line2'] = [4, 3, 2, 1]
    variables['line3'] = [1, 3, 5, 7]
    variables['user_id'] = id
    return render(request, 'interface/data.html', variables)
```

Then you need to render in the template (This isn't quite right but I'm sure you can work it out from here)

```
<div id="mychart"></div>
<script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.js"></script>
<script>
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
var data = [
datasets: [{
  data: {{line1}},
},{
  data: {{line2}},
},{
  data: {{line3}}
}
```